# How to interprate space between paragraphs in CSS?

Tags: html, css, spacing, paragraph

I'm trying to achieve the following:

Let's say I have a blog post that is written in basic HTML. I have a dilema on paragraphs spacing. Let's say I don't want to add a `<p>` tag for every paragraph, so I want only one that will render the following:

```
<p> 
This is my paragraph.
<!-- THIS SPACE I WANT IT IN CSS -->
This is my second paragraph.
</p>
```

Basically, I want to add an extra blank line every time when user space out its paragraph. I want it in CSS, without using two `<p>` tag for each paragraphs above.

How can I do that?

Comment: I think you're looking for `line-height` in CSS. It acts like a line-spacing between paragraphs everytime you want to break your paragraph

Comment: "Let's say I don't want to add a `<p>` tag for every paragraph" — Let's not. Start by writing high quality HTML. Then worry about how it looks.

Comment: Fair enough, @Quentin

Comment: Using `<br />` will solve your problem. For further information I suggest you check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple option which you can try. check snippet.

```css
p span {
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  This is my paragraph.
  <br><br> This is my second paragraph.
</p>


<h2>try this</h2>

<p>
  This is my paragraph.
</p>
<p>
  This is my second paragraph.
</p>



<h2>Or try this</h2>

<p>
  This is my paragraph.
  <span>  This is my second paragraph.</span>
</p>
```